# Sections move the navbar off screen

Tags: html, css

When I use my navbar, is it possible to have it not get pushed off of the screen?

I have tried wrapping them in separate divs with overflow hidden etc.

Ideally it will be on a static page with overflow:hidden; but this was just a quick mock up of what I have.

It may help to note that this is a 2 layer navigation, so this one is already inside another section.

I have a JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bz68252t/) for it.

HTML;

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
section{
height:100vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="home">
<p><b>Note:</b> If a !DOCTYPE is not specified, floating items can produce unexpected results.</p>
</section>

<section id="news">
<p>A background color is added to the links to show the link area. The whole link area is clickable, not just the text.</p>
</section>

<section id="contact">
<p><b>Note:</b> overflow:hidden is added to the ul element to prevent li elements from going outside of the list.</p>
<section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `100vh` for the section heights? Or perhaps use `position:fixed` on the navbar.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's only meant to stay there for this one section (with a 200px div underneath that this navbar is navigating through) and when i put fixed it goes offscreen in some crazy place

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` and your navbar stay always on the top.

Link:https://jsfiddle.net/bz68252t/2/

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed
}
section:first-of-type{
padding-top:2em;
}
```

Comment: It's only meant to stay there for this one section (with a 200px div underneath that this navbar is navigating through) and when i put fixed it goes offscreen in some crazy place

Comment: okk, change `section:first-of-type` with `section` and set padding top for all section